# In Spring MVC Controller, Form value is null when using Form Submit

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

From the menu option from another jsp, it executes "ReportPage" in controller and the combobox is populated with the values and upon submitting the form, it executes the "processReport" in the controller... **the form value is being printed as null i.e the comboxvalue.** How to get the comboBox Value in the controller?

Also just to let you know I have tried using $.POST(.. , comboBoxValue), I get the value in controller but later in the flow I have some problems so need to use the form Submit option only.

Will appreciate all your help.

```
**Controller :**

@Controller
public class ReportsController {

    @Resource(name = "meetingDao")
    private MeetingDao meetingDao;


    @RequestMapping(value="/ReportPage")
    @Secured({"ROLE_HOME"})
    public String reportPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session, ModelMap model) {
        List<Meeting> meetings = meetingDao.getMeetings();
        model.addAttribute("command", new ReportsForm());
        model.put("pickListMeetings",meetings);
        return "ReportPage";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/processReport")
    @Secured({"ROLE_HOME"})
    public String processReport(@ModelAttribute ReportsForm form, HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap modelMap, Principal principal) {
        String meeting = form.getSelectedMeeting();

        System.out.println("The Meeting----:"+form.getSelectedMeeting());// is null 

          try {        
              Vector v = PersonFactory.getInstance().getPeople( ds );         
          if (v.size() == 0) {               
              System.out.println("Invalid user id to send Email");
            } else {
                CGDSPerson p = (CGDSPerson) v.get(0);
                emailReport = p.getEmailId();
                System.out.println("Email report to  = "+emailReport);              
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        ....there is some code in here ...

        modelMap.addAttribute("command", new ReportLocation(location, "/bt/ReportPage.htm"));

        return "DisplayReport";

    }
}


**ReportPage.jsp**
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<span style="display: inline-block; align: center; width: 475px; vertical-align: top;">
    <div align="center">
        <img src="spacer.gif" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: none; width: 1px; height: 80px;"/>
        <br>

<form:form method="POST" style="margin-bottom:0;">

  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="BorderMain">
  <tr>
  <td align="left" valign="top">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Attendance Report :</legend>  
    <br> 
    <table align="center" width="100%" border="0"> 
    <tr>
    <td align="right" width="25%">
      Select a report : 
    </td>
    <td align="left" width="50%">
      <form:select path="selectedMeeting" id="selectedMeeting">
    <form:options items="${pickListMeetings}" itemValue="meetingId"
        itemLabel="name" />
    </form:select>

    </td>
    <td align="right" width="25%">
      <a href="#" class="fg-button ui-state-default fg-button-icon-left ui-corner-all" onclick="submitContainerNoReport()" id="reportPrint">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-print"></span>Print report 
      </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    </fieldset>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>

 </form:form>

        <hr>
    </div>
</span>             

<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

$(function() {
    $("#selectedMeeting").focus();
    $("#selectedMeeting").prepend("<option value=''>--- Select a Meeting ---</option>");
    $("#selectedMeeting").val('').prop('selected', true);
});

function submitContainerNoReport()
{
    formSubmit('/bt/processReport.htm');    
}

</SCRIPT>



**ReportForm.java**

public class ReportsForm extends RemanForm {

    private String selectedMeeting;

    /**
     * @return the selectedMeeting
     */
    public String getSelectedMeeting() {
        return selectedMeeting;
    }

    /**
     * @param selectedMeeting the selectedMeeting to set
     */
    public void setSelectedMeeting(String selectedMeeting) {
        this.selectedMeeting = selectedMeeting;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of formSubmit().

Comment: Jean: Thanks ..here is the formSubmit()
**code**
function formSubmit(type){
  displayLoading();  
  document.forms[0].action = type;  
  document.forms[0].submit();
}